# Make backup of Time Machine volume on Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

I have two laptops that back up via Time Machine to a Time Capsule. The shared volume on the Time Capsule contains two .sparsebundle files.

Can I copy those .sparsebundle files to an external hard disk and expect them to work as Time Machine backup resources again?

I usually send my Time Machine hard disks to a remote location every few months. With the Time Capsule I don't want to do that. That's whyt I want to copy the data and need to know whether I can still restore from it if I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I copy those .sparsebundle files to an external hard disk and expect them to work as Time Machine backup resources again?

Almost certainly yes.

### Modes and ownership

Ideally, use [`chmod`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html)(1) and [`chown`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html)(8) to have the mode and ownership, of the copy of the disk image, consistent with how Mountain Lion normally creates a *local* disk image for Time Machine.

#### Example

```
GPES3E-gjp4-1:~ gjp22$ sudo ls -al /Volumes/tall/com.apple.backupd/GPES3E-gjp4-1.sparsebundle/
Password:
total 16672
drwx------@ 3 root   staff     10  7 Jun 19:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 gjp22  staff     10  6 Jun 18:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff    500  7 Jun 18:03 Info.bckup
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff    500  7 Jun 18:03 Info.plist
drwx------  2 root   staff  78855  7 Jun 19:07 bands
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff    444  7 Jun 18:02 com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.bckup
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff    444  7 Jun 18:02 com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff   1473  6 Jun 21:28 com.apple.TimeMachine.Results.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   staff  10698  6 Jun 22:24 com.apple.TimeMachine.SnapshotHistory.plist
-rwx------  1 root   staff      0 19 Mar 19:36 token
```

– and for each band, you should have:

```
-rw-------  1 root  staff
```

#### Attaching the copy of the disk image

With Terminal, for the example above:

```
sudo hdiutil attach -readonly /Volumes/tall/com.apple.backupd/GPES3E-gjp4-1.sparsebundle/
```

If you use Terminal from within Recovery OS: you'll probably not need the `sudo` prefix to the command.

---

### Additional detail

> … whether I can still restore …

You require:

- a copy of a Time Machine destination, a copy that will be good for restoration
- not an additional Time Machine destination.

### Assumption

You wish the copy to be usable, for restoration only, in the event of **loss or failure of the Time Capsule**.

If the disk is attached from a local image where modes and ownership **vary from the norm** for a local image:

- OS X or Recovery OS *might* use that disk without difficulty; I *can't be certain*.

### Thoughts

If you're preparing for the possibility of loss or failure of a Time Capsule – and *restoration* from a copy of what was there – then think a step further, to *backing up* without the original Time Capsule. (If you wish the copy to be writeable by Time Machine, that could be a separate question.)

#### All things considered

It's probably quicker and simpler to use the external hard disk, or a part, as a Time Machine destination.

Comment: All those files are owned by me rather than root.